# Using condition-based logic in group wise transformations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of data that has a year column ('Year' and a dollar value column.  I want to group by the year, then for each row, determine if the row is above the group's median by 20% or below the group's median by 20%.

I tried the following:

```
def f(x):
    if x >= 1.2* np.median(x):
        return 'H'
    elif x<= .8* np.median(x):
        return 'L'

transformed = df.groupby('Year').transform(f)
```

But I get an error saying the truth value of an array is ambiguous.  This makes me think python is treating x in both the left and right hand side of the equation as the array of values, when in other transformation functions it knows on the left hand side the x is the row element and on the right hand side, where x is wrapped in an aggregation, x is the array.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
n = 20
dr = randint(2000, 2014, size=n)
df = DataFrame({'year': dr, 'dollar': hstack((poisson(1000, size=n / 2), poisson(100000, size=n / 2)))})

def med_replace(x):
    res = Series(index=x.index, name='med_cmp')
    med = x.dollar.median()
    upper = 1.2 * med
    lower = 0.8 * med
    res[x.dollar >= upper] = 'H'
    res[x.dollar <= lower] = 'L'
    res[(x.dollar > lower) & (x.dollar < upper)] = 'N'
    return x.join(res)

df.groupby('year').apply(med_replace)
```

yielding:

```
    dollar  year med_cmp
0     1016  2004       N
1      956  2002       L
2     1044  2010       N
3      985  2008       L
4     1038  2001       L
5      997  2001       L
6     1015  2001       L
7      971  2012       L
8     1017  2013       N
9     1040  2010       N
10   99760  2001       H
11   99835  2001       H
12  100017  2012       H
13   99532  2001       H
14  100311  2011       N
15  100344  2002       H
16  100209  2007       N
17   99988  2008       H
18  100204  2007       N
19  100996  2005       N
```

A numpy `ndarray` is not a valid argument to `bool` unless its `size` is 0 or 1. This means that you cannot evaluate its "truthiness" in an if statement unless it has 0 or 1 elements. This is why you're getting the error you reported.

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer to use `np.choose` which IMO is easier to read. :)

Comment: actually one question:  the answer above is based on one condition (is the row-value greater than the median?).  how would the answer be modified to check if its above 1.2*median OR below .8*median?  would it just be bools = x.dollar >= x.dollar.median()*1.2 OR x.dollar <= x.dollar.media()*.8? Thanks

Comment: i tried the above and i get the same error about truth value being ambiguous

Comment: Try reading up on [`numpy` comparison functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html?highlight=logical#comparison-functions). That should help you figure out what to do next.

Comment: hmmm, apologies for being a novice at this, but I can't figure it out.  I can get the 'or' logic to work using numpy comparison functions, but ultimately the logic I need is not 'or'...I'm trying to apply a case-statement-like function element wise that works on groups:  if element above 1.2* group_median, then assign 'h', if it's below .8*group_median, then assign 'l', the third logical possibility (it's within .2 of the group median) is ignored or assigned 'n'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've added those case-like issues to my answer